# err:NG 8001 mat-paginator is not known element in Angular 16

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material, angular-material-15, angular16

I am trying to add angular/material into the angular 16 project
For that i have created app.module.ts and mycomponent.module.ts & mycomponent.component.html.
Trying to run the 'ng serve' giving below err-

```
l:3:9 - error NG8001: 'mat-paginator' is not a known element:
1. If 'mat-paginator' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'mat-paginator' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.
3         <mat-paginator #paginator [pageSizeOptions]="[5,10,15]" />
```

Imported as well as Exported  the MatPaginatorModule in app.module.ts

```
import {mport { MatPaginatorModule } from '@angular/material/paginator';}
@NgModule({

imports: [ 

MatPaginatorModule ],
exports: [ 

MatPaginatorModule ],

schemas : [CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMAS],
```

Similarly imported in mycomponent.module.ts as below

`import {mport { MatPaginatorModule } from '@angular/material/paginator';}`

html is declared in mycomponent.component.html

```
<mat-paginator #paginator 
               [length]="100" 
               [pageSize]="10" 
               [pageSizeOptions]="[5, 10, 25, 100]">
</mat-paginator>
```

doing all these on 'ng serve' throwing above err

Comment: Remember: If your component is declared in a module, you need add the module to the array `imports` in the module **where you're declaring the component**. (you can also import a module that import the module). If your component is standalone, you need add in the array `imports` of the component.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your import statement for `matPaginator` has a mistake.

it should be

```
import { MatPaginatorModule } from '@angular/material/paginator';}
```

and not

```
import {mport { MatPaginatorModule } from '@angular/material/paginator';}
```